# i'm getting 12:00am instead of 12:00pm in android studio what should i do?

Tags: java, android, date, time

```
public static String getTime(String time) {

    String ampmTime = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date dt;
    try {
        dt = sdf.parse(time);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfs = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
        if (dt != null) {
            ampmTime = sdfs.format(dt);
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ampmTime;
}
```

In parameter string i'm sending 12:00:00 format so please i want this as 12:00pm instead of 12:00am . And others time is showing correctly like 13:30:00 to 1:30pm . So please help me??

Comment: Please consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: `LocalTime.parse("12:00:00").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IN")))`. Yields `12:00 PM` as requested. Yes, it’s true, with java.time you only need one formatter. Please break up into appropriate number of statements yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), When using **hh** you are telling the formatter the input time is an am/pm time. Use **HH** for 24hrs input.

Change the format to:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: You can accept the answer it you think it answered your question.

Comment: Thanks it is working now .

Comment: Great. Mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark next to the answer). This lets people know it was answered correctly.